# Duplicate Files - AppleScript

Tags: applescript, finder

I am trying to write an Apple Script that will duplicate two files from one folder to another. I tried to different methods but I keep getting an error.

**Method 1:**

```
tell application "Finder"

    set home_path to home as text

    set framework to alias (home_path & "Library:Developer:Xcode:DerivedData:ReaderKit-cusaxqpwrepxbfcmixaiszkolkkv:Build:Products:Debug-iphoneos:ReaderKit.framework")

    set bundle to alias (home_path & "Library:Developer:Xcode:DerivedData:ReaderKit-cusaxqpwrepxbfcmixaiszkolkkv:Build:Products:Debug-iphoneos:ReaderKit.framework")

    set destination to home_path & "Documents:WillowTree:BIA-Kelsey:BIA-Kelsey:ThirdParty"

    duplicate file framework to folder destination with replacing
    duplicate file bundle to folder destination with replacing
end tell
```

**Method 2**

```
tell application "Finder"

    set framework to "Macintosh HD:Users:nayef:Library:Developer:Xcode:DerivedData:ReaderKit-cusaxqpwrepxbfcmixaiszkolkkv:Build:Products:Debug-iphoneos:ReaderKit.framework"

    set bundle to "Macintosh HD:Users:nayef:Library:Developer:Xcode:DerivedData:ReaderKit-cusaxqpwrepxbfcmixaiszkolkkv:Build:Products:Debug-iphoneos:ReaderKit.bundle"

    set destination to "Macintosh HD:Users:User:nayef:Documents:WillowTree:BIA-Kelsey:BIA-Kelsey:ThirdParty"

    duplicate file framework to folder destination with replacing
    duplicate file bundle to folder destination with replacing
end tell
```

**The Error**

```
error "Finder got an error: Can’t set folder \"Macintosh HD:Users:User:nayef:Documents:WillowTree:BIA-Kelsey:BIA-Kelsey:ThirdParty\" to file \"Macintosh HD:Users:nayef:Library:Developer:Xcode:DerivedData:ReaderKit-cusaxqpwrepxbfcmixaiszkolkkv:Build:Products:Debug-iphoneos:ReaderKit.framework\"." number -10006 from folder "Macintosh HD:Users:User:nayef:Documents:WillowTree:BIA-Kelsey:BIA-Kelsey:ThirdParty"
```

What's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because "ReaderKit.framework" is not a file, use **folder**, **item** or **alias**

```
duplicate folder framework to folder destination with replacing
```